# c# how can i get my listbox item and add it quickly when i pressed checklistboxes

Tags: c#, forms, listbox, checklistbox

[image]

Hello I am still confuse to this how can I get my listbox items and when I click every checklistboxes and I want to add the numbers and display in the textbox. for example I check the checklistbox index 1 which contains 300 it display in the textbox. Then I check also my index 2 of checkboxlist contains 100 then it display 400. Then if I check my index 3 of my checkboxlist contains 200 it display 600 in the checkbox.

My code:

```
namespace ggg
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        textBox1.Clear();
        foreach (string s in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
        foreach (int i in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(300);
                decimal total = 300;
                textBox1.Text += total;
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(100);
                decimal total = 100;
                textBox1.Text += total;
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(200);
                decimal total = 200;
                textBox1.Text += total;

            }
        }


    }



}
}
```

Comment: what did you do , you must make some effort

Comment: i cant post my code wait

Comment: @gencklavyeler done sir

Comment: The code you have presented do not show what you have tried to bring in the sum to the last textbox!

Comment: Introduce a variable int `myvariable` and increment it in if statements. `if(i==0) {myvariable += 300; listbox2.Items.Add(300);}` then display `myvariable`

Comment: i try              decimal total = 100;
                    textBox1.Text += total; but he just list this

Comment: when i check my array[0] contains 300 he shows 300 then i check also array[1] contains 100 the textbox shows 300100

Comment: wait i edit the code

Comment: You are concatenating strings. `.Text` is a string object, so when you use `+=` on it, the existing string will be concatenated with new string. Use an `int` variable instead and store the value in text box at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can sum listbox items as this . After , you can set the total to textbox

```
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            total = total+ int.Parse(listBox2.Items[i].ToString());
        }
        textBox1.Text = total.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might get your job done. There are still better ways to do what you are looking for. But, this can be a good solution too! Considering your textbox name as `myTextBox`:

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0; // Add a variable to capture the sum

    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox2.Items.Clear();
    textBox1.Clear();
    foreach (string s in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    foreach (int i in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(300);
            sum += 300; // Add the value to sum
        }
        if (i == 1)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(100);
            sum += 100; // Add the value to sum
        }
        if (i == 2)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(200);
            sum += 200; // Add the value to sum
        }
    }

    // Finally, show the sum in text box
    myTextBox.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks man you're the best :D long live god bless hmmm.. sir for design sir what is better checkbox or checklistbox ? my checklistbox is not like friendly user for me becase the box is so hard to click

Comment: @HeiSciff, If you add group of `checkboxes` there would be too many UI objects with too many handles. So, bad for performance if it is a big application. Plus, you would have to write event handleers for individual checkboxes. I would recommend `checklistbox`. For the issue you mention with `checklistbox`, can you try setting `CheckOnClick` property and see if it makes a difference?